# Kotlin. Get distinct values from collection

Tags: kotlin, collections, distinct

Data looks like this

```
    class Person (
        var id:Int, 
        var name:String
    )
    class Option (
        var level:Int
    )
    val p1 = Person(1, "A")
    val p2 = Person(2, "B")
    val opt1 = Option((0..1000).random())
    val opt2 = Option((0..1000).random())
    val opt3 = Option((0..1000).random())
    val opt4 = Option((0..1000).random())
    
    val arr = listOf(
        listOf(p1,p2,opt1), 
        listOf(p1,p2,opt2), 
        listOf(p1,p2,opt3), 
        listOf(p2,p1,opt4)
    )
```

I would like to get "A" and "B" as unique values of name.

It's easy if collection looks like this:

```
val simple = listOf(p1,p2,p2,p1).distinctBy{it.name}
simple.forEach {
    println(it.name)
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a list of lists, each of which seems to have some implicit structure, instead of a list of some suitable object?

Comment: Actually data is from web server in JSON format and contains JSON arrays and objects. I convert it to my classes. The list is just to simply my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work as expected:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val p1 = Person(1, "A")
    val p2 = Person(2, "B")
    val opt1 = Option((0..1000).random())
    val opt2 = Option((0..1000).random())
    val opt3 = Option((0..1000).random())
    val opt4 = Option((0..1000).random())

    val arr = listOf(
        listOf(p1,p2,opt1),
        listOf(p1,p2,opt2),
        listOf(p1,p2,opt3),
        listOf(p2,p1,opt4)
    )

    val distinctNames = arr.flatten().mapNotNull {
        when(it) {
            is Person -> it.name
            else -> null
        }
    }.distinct()

    println(distinctNames)
}

class Person (
    var id:Int,
    var name:String
)

class Option (
    var level:Int
)
```

---

However, I would advise you to replace the nested Lists if possible so that you can avoid the `when` block while mapping. If possible I would suggest `Triple` class instead as follows:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val p1 = Person(1, "A")
    val p2 = Person(2, "B")
    val opt1 = Option((0..1000).random())
    val opt2 = Option((0..1000).random())
    val opt3 = Option((0..1000).random())
    val opt4 = Option((0..1000).random())

    val arr = listOf(
        Triple(p1,p2,opt1),
        Triple(p1,p2,opt2),
        Triple(p1,p2,opt3),
        Triple(p2,p1,opt4)
    )

    val distinctNames = arr.flatMap { listOf(it.first.name, it.second.name) }
         .distinct()
    println(distinctNames)
}
```

---

Another possibility if you want/need to keep the nested Lists would be the following (*thanks @gidds for the hint*):

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val p1 = Person(1, "A")
    val p2 = Person(2, "B")
    val opt1 = Option((0..1000).random())
    val opt2 = Option((0..1000).random())
    val opt3 = Option((0..1000).random())
    val opt4 = Option((0..1000).random())

    val arr = listOf(
        listOf(p1,p2,opt1),
        listOf(p1,p2,opt2),
        listOf(p1,p2,opt3),
        listOf(p2,p1,opt4)
    )

    val distinctNames = arr.flatten().mapNotNull { (it as? Person)?.name }
        .distinct()

    println(distinctNames)
}
```

Comment: Could you simplify the `when` block to something like `(it as? Person)?.name`?

Comment: That is in fact simpler ;)  Thanks for the hint! I will update my answer.

Comment: The last one is cool.

Comment: Is your issue solved now? If it is and my answer helped you consider upvoting it and even accepting it as the answer so that it can be ”closed” and others can benefit from it and easily understand which could be a possible solution for similar questions ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Another option can be to create a custom class to represent your inner lists.

```kotlin
class PersonOption(
    val person1: Person,
    val person2: Person,
    val option: Option
)

val arr = listOf(
    PersonOption(p1, p2, opt1),
    PersonOption(p1, p2, opt2),
    PersonOption(p1, p2, opt3),
    PersonOption(p2, p1, opt4)
)

val names = arr.flatMap { listOf(it.person1.name, it.person2.name) }.distinct()
println(names)
```